# Notepad++ space within a keyword in Autocomplete

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete

I created my autocomplete file after reading some documents. The problem is i cant add space within a keyword. My keyword is "define method .xx"
But notepad++ recognise all of the worda separately.
Is there any way to do it.
I read somewhere that i will have to edit some notepad files in c.
I am pretty new, so please can anyone guide me. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible.

Citing the documentation article
[Auto Completion in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion),
section
[How to create keyword auto-completion definition files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion#How_to_create_keyword_auto-completion_definition_files):

> The basic character set used to recognise keywords is made of
>   **letters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 digits and the underscore**. In future release of Notepad++, you will be able to add more characters - the dot is a likely candidate - by specifying the additionalWordChars parameter in the environment. The value will be a string with all the extra parameters without any separators. However, this additionalWordChars is still not working (Notepad++ v.6.5.2)!

The blank is not listed here as being one of the characters that you
may include in an auto-complete keyword.